# Get hid device model using HidLibrary in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, usb, hid

I'm using .net and the HidLibrary (https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary). I can get the PID and VID of the connected usb device, but I can't get the actual model or product name of the device (Ex. M25 25 lb Digital Postal Scale), how can I get this kind of information. I'm relatively new to .Net and windows programming.

Is there a way to get the entire device info like Device Name, Vendor Name, Model etc using those 2 values?